# Erro no include_once usando AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

O código está no link pois
esta em um sistema de pasta.

PROBLEMA:

Tenho uma arquitetura MVC.Dentro do view tenho
uma classe que contem um formulário de cadastro que 
esta na classe tela_inicial.Os dados dos campos do form
são enviados para um script que contem um ajax
esse ajax irá mandar as informações para a classe 
usuário controle e depois irá haver um retorno para 
o script pela função (done).

O erro esta acontecendo na classe Usuario_dao ,toda vez que tento 
incluir a classe conexão presente no pacote singleton obtenho um erro 
que é emitido pela função done do ajax.

No código deixei comentado a inclusão mas vocês podem retirar o comentário 
do include_once da classe Usuario_dao e inserirem os dados ,que irão ver o erro.
Essa é a imagem do erro quando incluo a classe conexão:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[LINK DO ARQUIVO](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NWi_Wylqk45IPZOLpf_TxG5JLELapZ7w?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thiago baixei seu sistema e debuguei, coloquei a classe Conexao.php dentro de onde está Usuario_dao.php, e fiz o seguinte include:

```
include 'Conexao.php';
```

logo apos isso o alert de test funcionou normalmente. ou seja o código estava ok

Mas para você resolver seu erro, você está com o classico erro do URL, coloque o url absoluto, (fiz isso no seu sistema e funcionou)

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/APP/MODEL/SINGLETON/Conexao.php");
```

Comment: usei a url absoluto e funcionou.Valeu!

Comment: é nois thiago! valeu por considerar como resposta e votar como util :D